# How to collapse a face in a mesh in Computer Graphics ( How to deal with the surrounding vertices)?

Tags: graphics, 3d, mesh

I can collapse a edge , but i do not know how to collapse a face . How to deal with the surrounding vertices)?

Comment: please be more specific and also post your code and what you have already tried

Answer (score 0):

Removing a face does not affect your vertices in the general case. By removing a face you just remove the information that 3 vertices form a face. These vertices can still take part in other faces.

If you actually want to remove a face from your mesh a hole will be generated in your mesh. Consider the following mesh patch consisting of 3 faces.
[image]
 If you decide to remove F2 then the final patch will consist of 2 faces as seen below. 
[image]
Note that you do not have to rename your faces. I did that to emphasize that there will be 2 faces left.

After releasing the above the way to implement this depends on how you have represented your mesh,but in general you would do something like that:

```
//the following is pseudo code
if(faceToRemove.isBoarderFace()){
    completelyRemoveEdgesThatOnlyBelongedToThisFace(); //if two edge get removed one vertex needs to get removed
}
setTheRemainingEdgesAsBoarderEdges();
removeFaceFromFaceList();
```

If your mesh does not have holes prior to removing the face than you will not need to remove any vertices from your mesh.

Also take a look at [CGAL's graphical explanation](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/BGL/group__PkgBGLEulerOperations.html#gacfae7ff8e782da55b941e4487e86c738) .